# Regex to take values based on multiple checks

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have string

```
string s="someMethod(999,'xyz')"
```

and I want to take 999 and xyz in to array.
what could be the best possible way instead of splitting it by '(' first
and by ',' and then by '\''

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: s.Split('(') follwed by x=s[1].Split(',') followed by y=x[1].Split('\'') followed by y[1].Split('\'')

Comment: You should add that to your question and state why that did not work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use regex for that.

You can use [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx), [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) and [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) methods like;

```
string s = "someMethod(999,'xyz')";
string BetweenBrackets = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("(") + 1, s.IndexOf(")") - s.IndexOf("(") - 1);
string[] array = BetweenBrackets.Split(new char[] { ',', '\'' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Console.WriteLine(array[0]); //999
Console.WriteLine(array[1]); //xyz
```

Here a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/oArTX1).

Comment: using the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx) and specifying `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`, you'd be able to use `array[0]` and `array[1]` instead. To me, that is more intuitive than using `array[2]`

Comment: @Default Good call. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^.+?\((.+?),'(.+?)'\)$
```

$1: 999,
$2: xyz

Full code:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^.+?\((.+?),'(.+?)'\)$");
string[] parameters = new string[2];
parameters[0]=r.Match(s).Groups[1].Value;
parameters[1]=r.Match(s).Groups[2].Value;
```

If you're not sure that there will be single quotes, use `'?` instead of `'`

Comment: jerry the values 999, xyz are not static. I just want to capture the method parameters of "someMethod" in two variables

Comment: I know they aren't static. I mean that $1 will have 999 and $2 will have xyz

Comment: Jerry's right, it works. Just a doubt of mine, won't a regex like "\\((.+),'(.+)'" do the same job?